# How to upload to local storage?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the model method below, which uploads to an AWS S3 bucket in production. This works. The problem is that it did the same within the development and testing environment (before I added the if...else statement). Therefore, I would like to extend the model method so that it uploads to local file storage when within a development or testing environment.

But I'm not sure how to add this. I've been following [Hartl's railstutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/user_microposts#sec-image_upload_in_production) and for basic image uploading he uses the fog gem. But he uses an uploader there, which does not apply to my situation. Not sure if and how I should use the fog gem in my situation. Could anyone suggest the code for the `else` part of the model method below?

```
def self.upload_file(id)
  if Rails.env.production?
    s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(
           region: Rails.application.secrets.AWS_REGION,
           credentials: Aws::Credentials.new(
             Rails.application.secrets.S3_ACCESS_KEY,
             Rails.application.secrets.S3_SECRET_KEY)
          )
    myfile = 'app/assets/emptyfile.xml'
    filename = "myfiles/#{id}/file-#{id}.xml"
    obj = s3.bucket(Rails.application.secrets.S3_BUCKET_CONCEPTMAP).object(filename)
    obj.upload_file(myfile)
    Conceptmap.create!(organization_id: id, myfile: obj.public_url)
  else
    ### Do the same as above but now to local file storage instead of S3 bucket ###
  end
end
```

Comment: Have you mounted same Uploader i.e.: `PictureUploader`? And why `fog` is not suitable in your case when you are also using aws s3 for production?

Comment: No, I don't need any uploader. The model method is called upon from a controller action (upon the creation of a new account).

Comment: You should create a new uploader to handle file upload logic. Modularity will really help you in further development and in SDLC. The code you are writing in your model is not meant to be there. Most of it should be in uploader and initializer files

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into using carrierwave uploader to upload the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiling our comment conversation conclusion here so that others can take help from this:

You should create a new uploader as mentioned in the tutorial you are following. Move uploader related code to that new uploader to modularize things. Most of the code that is lying in `self.upload_file(id)` currently, is meant to be in uploader.

it will solve your problem.